# JPQL - Joins - MultipleTables and empty ResultList

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jpa

I have a query in JPQL through 5 tables, but if one of the table is NULL, the whole query fails and resultList is empty and it throws the exception. On the other hand if all tables do not contain null, it works as expected.

How to implement it to return all objects where table is not null and objects where is null as null? So I would get - Object1[], null, null, null for example... and not only empty result list...
Thank you very much :)

```
public List<Object[]> getAdditionalInformation(String ppin) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p, pl, r, d, do FROM Patient p JOIN p.placements pl JOIN pl.room r"
            + " JOIN r.department d JOIN d.doctors do where p.pin = :ppin");
    query.setParameter("ppin", ppin);

    return query.getResultList();
}

@Transactional
    public AdditionalPD getAdditional(String ppin) {
        List<Object[]> list = hr.getAdditionalInformation(ppin);

        AdditionalPD adp = new AdditionalPD();
        Patient patient = null;
        Placement placement = null;
        Room room = null;
        Department department = null;
        Doctor doctor = null;

        for(Object[] object : list) {
            patient = (Patient) object[0];
            placement = (Placement) object[1];
            room = (Room) object[2];
            department = (Department) object[3];
            doctor = (Doctor) object[4];
        }

        adp.setPatientFirstName(patient.getFirstName());
        adp.setPatientLastName(patient.getLastName());
        adp.setAge(countAge(ppin));
        adp.setFrom(placement.getFrom());
        adp.setTo(placement.getTo());
        adp.setRoomName(room.getName());
        adp.setDepartmentName(department.getName());
        adp.setDoctorFirstName(doctor.getFirstName());
        adp.setDoctorLastName(doctor.getLastName());

        return adp;
    }

@GetMapping("/additional/pin/{ppin}")
    public String additionalInformation(@PathVariable String ppin, Model model) {

        AdditionalPD adp = has.getAdditional(ppin);

        model.addAttribute("adp", adp);

        return "additional";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. JPQL joins are `INNER JOIN`s by default.